# How to vectorize one hot encoding loop in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize the loop in this code?

```
def get_onehot(y):
    categories = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    arr = np.zeros((y.shape[0], len(categories)))
    for i in range(y.shape[0]):
        n = y[i]
        arr[i][n] = 1
    return arr

>>> get_onehot(np.array([0, 2, 5]))
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

E.g I assume this is not the most efficient way of doing it and I am wondering if there is a code improvement available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use scikit-learn, here is a NumPy way:

```
import numpy as np

def get_onehot(y, n=10):
    return np.eye(n)[y]

get_onehot(np.array([0, 2, 5]))

# array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

[`np.eye` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html)